# How to pass a variable in button id and then send that id to ajax data?

Tags: json, ajax, model-view-controller

I am passing id of the product to button id and then through Ajax data, I'm sending that product id to the controller

```
for(var i=0;i<productsJSON.length;i++)
{
    var td5 = document.createElement('td');
    td5.innerHTML = "<br><button type='button' id="+product.id+"onclick='Addtocart() ' >Add To Cart</button><br>";
}

function Addtocart() {

    var quantity = document.getElementsByName("quantity").item(0).value;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: 'pid=' + this.id + '&quantity=' + quantity,
        url: "ProductController",
        success: function(content) {
            console.log(content);
            alert('done');
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Which variable are you trying to send? What happens when you run your code? Is there an error? If so, what exactly is the error?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a JSON object.
Here I set data from an HTML form using the GET method.

```
$.ajax(
        {
            type: "GET",
            data: $("#form").serialize(),
            url: "url",
            success: function(data)
            {
                # Code
            },
            error: function()
            {
                # Code
            }
        }
    );
```